# CakePHP - Call camel-case action methods but with underscores in URL

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I keep my action method names camel-case like `myActionMethod()`, but use `/controller/my_action_method` in the URL?

I was sure Cake does the inflection for this automatically, but apparently not.  I have to name my methods like `my_action_method` as well, which I don't like.

Even better would be a solution for hyphenated URLs for SEO, rather than underscores.

Comment: you can use routing; but why break convention over something that trivial?

Comment: Is there a route that would globally convert all URLs automatically?

I don't see method naming conventions as something trivial.  I like to stick to coding conventions, and as such always make camel-case method names.  Seems stupid to have some underscored and some camel-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yoy need add this string to file app/core/routes.php

```
Router::connect ('/controller/action-action/*',array('controller'=>'somecontroller', 'action'=>'actionaction'));
```

for example:

```
Router::connect ('/users/view-user/*',array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'viewUser'));
```

/users/view-user/
/users/viewuser/
both url have the same action

Comment: This looks like you have to do that for every action in your application you want to connect.  There could be hundreds.

Comment: i'm added small example, hope it helps, sorry because explain something on english for me, it isn't easy